# How to use redis username with password in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, redis

Currently I have the below service configured in my `docker-compose` which works correct with redis password. However, I would like to use also redis username together with password. Is there any similar command to `requirepass` or something else to enable `username`?

```
version: '3.9'
volumes:
  redis_data: {}
networks:
  ee-net:
    driver: bridge
services:
  redis:
    image: 'redis:latest'
    container_name: redis
    hostname: redis
    networks:
      - ee-net
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    command: '--requirepass redisPassword'
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
```

Answer (score 19):

You can specify a config file

```bash
$ cat redis.conf
requirepass password
#aclfile /etc/redis/users.acl
```

Then add the following to your docker compose file

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    command: ["redis-server", "/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
    volumes:
      - ./redis.conf:/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Then you will get the password requirements

```bash
redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> ping
(error) NOAUTH Authentication required.
127.0.0.1:6379> AUTH password
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> ping
PONG
```

You may want to look into the ACLs line commented out there if you require more fine grained control

Answer (score 13):

Passing the users as environment flags was enough for me. Here's a sample using [redis-stack](https://redis.io/docs/stack/get-started/install/docker/#environment-variables).

```yaml
  redis:
    image: redis/redis-stack:6.2.6-v7
    restart: always
    environment:
      REDIS_ARGS: "--requirepass password --user username on >password ~* allcommands --user default off nopass nocommands"
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis:/data
```

This disables the "default" redis user and activates user called "username" with a password of "password". the [ACL syntax](https://redis.io/docs/management/security/acl/)  is well covered by Redis docs.

The sample above also works with [redis-stack-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/redis/redis-stack-server) image. The idea is to take advantage of this section in the [Redis config documentation](https://redis.io/docs/management/config/):

> The format of the arguments passed via the command line is exactly the same as the one used in the redis.conf file, with the exception that the keyword is prefixed with --.

Comment: This only works with `redis/redis-stack`. Does not work with `redis/latest` image. Also your example is not clear as you example password is "password". Note the `>password` is the literal password. so if your password is `mypassword` you need to adjust it to `>mypassword`

Answer (score 3):

You're missing `redis-server` in your command. Please try the following command instead:

```
redis-server --requirepass redisPassword
```

In case you want to run your Redis server with a configuration file, use this command:

```
command: redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
volumes:
    - /local/path/to/redis.conf:/path/to/redis.conf
```

To define a password in your configuration file, use `requirepass` as shown below:

```
requirepass redisPassword
```

### References

- [Redis Configuration](https://redis.io/docs/management/config-file/)
- [How do I set a password for Redis?](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/issues/176)

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers seemed to answer the question directly, which is how to create a custom username **and** a custom password with the `redis:latest` container image with docker-compose. (Not just applying a custom password for the default user)

First of all, there isn't an easily supported way to do this with the `redis:latest` image. You can accomplish this directly with redis-stack images, but that is not what op requested. Not to say its impossible, but the way redis handles permissions with its access control lists requires you to create a user and grant permissions with their acl files in a script.

I was able to accomplish creating a custom user, assign them a password, and
permissions with docker-compose + Dockerfile + a custom-entrypoint.sh. I also added the ability to disable the default user as well. These are the steps:

1. Directory structure

```
.
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── .env
│   └── .env.dev.msg-broker.reddis
└──  services
    └──  msg-broker
        ├── custom-entrypoint.sh
        └── Dockerfile.dev
```

2. Configure your docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  msg-broker:
    container_name: "msg-broker"
    build:
      context: ./services/msg-broker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    env_file:
      - ./.env/.env.dev.msg-broker.reddis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

3. Configure the env var file. You can also accomplish this by applying the variables directly in the docker-compose.yaml by creating an `environment` key instead. This is where you can configure you username and password, and if you want to keep the default user or not.

```
REDIS_USERNAME=myadmin
REDIS_PASSWORD=MyAdm1nP455w0rd
REDIS_DISABLE_DEFAULT_USER="true"
```

4. Configure Dockerfile, notice how the custom-entrypoint.sh is copied over and ran instead of the default one directly.

```
FROM redis:latest

# Copy the custom entrypoint script
COPY custom-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/custom-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/custom-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["custom-entrypoint.sh"]
```

5. Configure the custom-entrypoint.sh. This is where the real configuration happens.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Set up Redis configuration directory
mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/redis

# Dynamically generate Redis configuration and ACL files here, using environment variables
echo "aclfile /usr/local/etc/redis/custom_aclfile.acl" > /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

# Generate ACL file using environment variables
if [ -n ${REDIS_USERNAME} ] && [ -n ${REDIS_PASSWORD} ]; then
    echo "user ${REDIS_USERNAME} on allkeys allchannels allcommands >${REDIS_PASSWORD} " > /usr/local/etc/redis/custom_aclfile.acl
fi

# Disable default user
if [ $(echo ${REDIS_DISABLE_DEFAULT_USER}) == "true" ]; then
    echo "user default off nopass nocommands" >> /usr/local/etc/redis/custom_aclfile.acl
fi

# Call the original Docker entrypoint script with redis-server and the path to the custom Redis configuration
exec docker-entrypoint.sh redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

6. Run it

```
docker-compose up --build
```

You *should* be able to adjust the permissions for your users needs by tweaking the `echo "user ${REDIS_USERNAME} on allkeys allchannels allcommands >${REDIS_PASSWORD} " > /usr/local/etc/redis/custom_aclfile.acl` command in the custom-entrypoint script. I know the permissions I assigned give my user god like control, however I needed this for my celery instance to work, see [this post](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/8724) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to look for an answer to a similar question I stumbled across this thread, so here's what I found after digging a bit more. Disclosure, I'm using the [`bitnami/redis`](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/redis) Docker Image for my Redis requirements.

Redis provides a `default` user and it is possible to add a password to this particular user. For the Bitnami Image, it is possible to add a password for authentication by passing the `REDIS_PASSWORD=password` environment variable.

[image: screenshot from the Redis ACL docs]

Thereafter all clients can authenticate as the `default` user by connecting through the URL;

```
redis://default:password@ip-address:6379
```

Now of course, using default authentication credentials does not sound like a good idea which is why it is recommended you go through the detailed [Redis Access Control List (Redis ACL)](https://redis.io/docs/management/security/acl) documentation for more information on the same.

With a proper ACL practice in place, the Redis URL would look something like:

```
redis://naruto:kageno-bunshin-jutsu@172.133.129.1:2451
```

...where `naruto` is a "user" with proper ACL permissions in place and `kageno-bunshin-jutsu` is the password for the user. The `172.133.129.1` is the IP address of the node where the Redis instance is accessible and `2451` is the port number.

Answer (score 0):

I had been using Redis via docker with the command

`docker run -d --name redis-stack-server -p 6379:6379 redis/redis-stack-server:lates`

I could spin up a password-protected redis-stack-server docker instance via the command

`docker run -d --name redis-stack-server -p 6379:6379 -e REDIS_ARGS="--requirepass <password>" redis/redis-stack-server:latest`

you can login into this instance via RedisInsight or any other client using  and user name `"default"` which is the default username in redis